# Azure DevOps. Find Invocies

Tags: azure-devops

We have a few Azure subscriptions but are unable to find our Azure DevOps usage and bills via Subscriptions > Cost analysis  as [indicated in the documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/billing-faq?view=azure-devops#understanding-your-bill)

Cost Analysis reports that we are not using Azure DevOps.
[image]

Why is this happening and how can we evaluate our Azure DevOps usage?

Answer (score 0):

You want to look within the Azure DevOps portal itself rather than the Azure portal. This is found at [dev.azure.com](https://dev.azure.com).

The billing is done on a per Organization basis. If you navigate to `Organisation settings` in the bottom left of the home page, and then navigate to the `Billing` pane, all the info should be in there.